# Creating a printful order using the API with Django python

Tags: django, api, django-views

i am trying to create order with printful API, i don't understand where i am wrong.
the error that comes out of me is:

```
{"code":400,"result":"Invalid request: missing order element","error":{"reason":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid request: missing order element"}}
```

this is the code, for those who have already integrated it what is the variant_id and how can I find it?
Someone help me please

```
import requests
import json

@login_required
def test(request):

    # variabili per connessione
    token = "4XYO4WBEGWtpQoTtRBh1xF4ulQnt8dLKfyjXpxFt"
    url = "https://api.printful.com/"
    header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    # dati ordine
    payload = {
        "recipient": {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "address1": "Via milano 55",
            "city": "Arese",
            "state_name": "Milano",
            "country_code": "IT",
            "zip": "20020"
        },
        "items": [
            {   
                "variant_id": 1,
                "name": "Digital Tech",
                "quantity": 1,
                "retail_price": "40.00",
            }
        ]
    }
    crea = requests.post(url + 'orders', params = payload, headers = header)





    ottieni = requests.get(url + 'store/products', headers = header)
    context = {'test': ottieni.json(), 'crea': crea.text}
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a wrong you must have to pass data in order to post your data.

Try with this!

```
requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),haders=headers)
```